# ggplot two lines on same chart from data with different number of rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I'm always having this problem where I need to plot two lines on a chart, but there are different number of rows in my data.  I keep getting this error and I wish I could solve it once and for all:

> Error: (converted from warning) Removed 5 row(s) containing missing
>   values (geom_path).

Here is some sample data (I didn't manually add the NAs):

```
datamre <- structure(list(xR = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, NA, NA, NA, NA), received = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 
0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 
0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 
0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, 0.1666667, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), xD = 0:34, demand = c(0, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 
0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.08333333, 0.16666667, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 
0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.41666667, 0.41666667, 0.41666667
)), row.names = c(NA, 35L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the simple code I'm using:

```
df <- data.frame(datamre)
ggplot(df) +
   geom_line(aes(xR,received)) +
   geom_line(aes(xD,demand))
```

Comment: The warning is not an error. It's just reminding you that 5 data points were not plotted because there are `NA`s present in the `x` or `y` aesthetic. This is not something to be concerned about *per se*. Perhaps the `NA` were introduced when you cast the data into long form?

Comment: But it's listed as an error and nothing is plotted.

Comment: Interesting. I get a plot. See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i2aO.png).

Comment: What am I doing wrong because I get this all the time?

Comment: This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605672/error-converted-from-warning-ignoring-unknown-aesthetics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(df[complete.cases(df),]) +
  geom_line(aes(xR,received)) +
  geom_line(aes(xD,demand))
```

Comment: That worked - thanks, but I still don't understand why Ian Campbell has a solution without adding "complete.cases" (I assume).

Comment: He may be having a valid reason. There a difference between both cases. If we plot without adding complete cases, received and demand lines will be drawn with available data individually in each variable. If you compare the plot you have got with the one produced my Ian Campbell, you could see the difference.