# ggplotly: how to use a special variable with a standard variable in the text aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm creating an interactive plot and I want the tooltip to show the time (a variable in the dataset) and the count (a variable calculated by ggplot). Using the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569551/date-format-in-hover-for-ggplot2-and-plotly) I can set one or the other, but not both... Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

data(ChickWeight)

ChickWeight %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time,
             text = paste(format(Time), "-", ..count..))) +
  geom_bar()

plotly::ggplotly(tooltip = "text")
```

This fails with the error `object 'Time' not found`, but both `text = format(Time)` and `text = ..count..` work individually. How can I include both values in the text aesthetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `..count..` notation has been superseded by `after_stat(count)`, but in either case, this can only be used in a layer employing this statistical transformation, not the global plot aesthetic mapping. The problem is, you can't use the `text` aesthetic anywhere *other* than the global aesthetic mapping.

The obvious way round this is to manipulate the data *before* plotting, which is just as straightforward as getting ggplot to do it for you:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data(ChickWeight)

(ChickWeight %>%
  count(Time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, text = paste(Time, "-", n))) +
  geom_bar()) %>%
  plotly::ggplotly()
```

[image]